# How to recenter map in iPhone app on zoom in/out using MKMapView

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, zooming

I am developing an iPhone application in which I need to show an image at a specific Latitude & Longitude on a Map. The requirement is - Even if the user zooms in or out on this map screen, the map control should automatically center itself after the zoom, to the same Lat & Long. I am using MKMapView.

I have tried to go through all available documentation. However, I could not come across any callback or other method that will allow me to achieve the objective.

One alternative is to handle touch events. However, I find that as a very complicated solution. And I hope that a simpler alternative exists. Any ideas on the above?

Can you please help? Any example will be appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903913/how-to-recenter-map-on-zoom-in-iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `MKMapViewDelegate` and then try this:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:locationManager.coordinate animated:NO];
}
```

Replace `locationManager` with whatever the name of your `CLLocationManager` is.